# equation for the accumulated probability of y with x attempts with the probability increasing by k every attempt

Tags: probability

I'm trying to create a equation simulating the gacha probability of a game. Here are the rules:

- From attempts 1-50, the probability of getting a unit is 2%
- From attempts 51+, this probability increases by 2% every attempt, so it's 4% at 51, 6% at 52 and so on.

I want to create an equation that represents my accumulated probability of obtaining one or more copies of this unit given x attempts.
[So far, my equation looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2eBs.png)

There is an issue with this equation, which is that after 50 attempts, I assumed that the accumulated probability is (98%-2%×n)^x where n is the no. of attempts after 50, when the correct equation should be (98%)×(98%)×...×(98%-2%×n). I don't really know enough about equations to solve such a relationship between the x and y values, so can anyone help me out?

Comment: What does "within $x$ attempts" mean?  Do you mean the *first* $x$ attempts or might the string start anywhere?  In any case,  assuming you meant "at least one" instead of "exactly one", it is easier to work backwards.  Work out the probability that there are $0$ units in those $x$ trials.

Comment: @lulu I'll edit my question to be more specific, but I basically mean that given a value of x, what are my accumulated chances of getting one or more units? the possibility of there having 0 units is given by (98%)×(96%)×(94%)×...×(98%-2%×n), this was what I already concluded, just that I did not know how to write this as an actual equation.

Comment: It's hard to follow what you have written, in part because you haven't tried to format it properly.  Again, do you mean the *first* $x$ attempts or can you start at some higher trial number? In any case, you are almost certainly better off with a program...the formula won't be great.  For instance, if you look at $x$ trials within the first $50$ then the answer is $1-(1-.02)^x$.  After that, you'll need a separate term in the product for every trial after $\# 50$.